# PDF in Texmaker does not update after running Quick Build or PDFLatex

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

When I run make changes to my document and run Quick Build it does not update the PDF in the quick view or the document stored in the folder. I have always just ran Quick Build but I have tried to run PDFLatex and Latex as well to see if it would work and still no changes. Just a few days ago it was working just fine but my computer updated this morning and now it will not work. I'm assuming this has something to do with it. 
I realize this is a problem many have encountered but after reading and trying all that I could find, they either wouldn't work or the discussions came to a dead end.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. So it doesn't work? Does the most minimal Hello World example work? Please try and give feedback what might not have worked. Error messages or the like.

Comment: No it doesn't work. After I run "Quick Build","PDFLatex","Latex" it does show an error but it doesn't update the PDF.